# How can I run a unlock.exe file to decrypt a Western Digital hard disk?

Tags: 11.10, wine, encryption, external-hdd

As I'm a first time user I doesn't how to use Ubuntu 11.10.

Before my OS installation I backed up all the files in a Western Digital hard disk which is password protected. After I finished my installation I can't get access to my hard-disk because it has a program which is called `unlock.exe` and I can't open it, so please help me with a solution.

Also I had used Wine Windows Program Loader, and the error message generated was "The application has encountered an unexpected error and it is exiting now". So what shall I do?

Answer (score 2):

You would be better decrypting the drive from a Windows computer and then simply using TrueCrypt to encrypt it in the future.

If you do not have access to a Windows computer then you might want to give TrueCrypt a shot if you also know what cypher(s) was use to encrypt the drive.(Ex. AES-256)